# How to access templates from external repos dynamically

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, ado

I am working on a solution to implement a single Azure pipeline for our wide spread micro service architecture i.e., the single big application has diverted into nearly 100+ repos where each will be having its own pipeline. So to create a pipeline for all this repos i'm using azure templates i.e., tasks and variables templates. The variables template is to override some steps in tasks template e.g. one repo/branch wants to not run sonar step/task, then its overridden by settings vars and this vars template is present in each repo's and branches to give them the flexibility to customise pipeline as per the development need.

So now i have created a single central pipeline called app-pipeline, which gets triggered by every backend repo's and branches by making use of multi-repo triggers on az piplein. But now i have a problem in accessing those vars template file from the application repos dynamically depending on who triggered the pipeline.
For example: The pipeline config, task templates are present in separate repo called 'app-pipelines' and a pipeline is created for this repo. Now the variables template is in application(backend) repos which i need to make use with the help of **resources.repository** that too dynamically and its failing.

```
trigger:
  - none
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: repo1
      name: backend_repo_50
      trigger:
        - master
        - feature/*
        - bugfix/*
    - ...
variables:
  -template: ${{ format(‘release-params.yml@{0}’, variables[‘Build.Repository.Name’]) }}

jobs:
  - job: build-and-test
    steps:
      - template: build.yml # present in same repo where pipeline config is present
        parameters:
          node_version: 19.x
      - ${{ if eq(‘true’, variables.sonar_enabled) }}
        - template: sonar-test.yml`
```

**Solutions tried**:-
As i mentioned in code i tried to use repo name then found out its agent-scoped and only available during runtime.

*Approach 2*: tried creating an intermediate variable transform yaml file. So it exposes an parameter to get repo name and it has a single job which consumes the variables and try to export it to the next jobs/stages using json format. Then use this in following tasks.

```
jobs: 
 - job: init
   steps:
     - script: |
         user_override=$(echo $var1 | jq -r 'to_entries | map(select(.key |   startswith("custom."))) | map(.key |= sub("^custom\\."; "")) | from_entries | @text' )
         echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=customVars;isoutput=true;]$user_override"
       env:
          var1: "${{ convertToJson(variables) }}"
```